# Notifications don't work after

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I learn writing Android apps and I want to make a simple application, that would give to user a daily notification.

I create an app, but it works only when I set the time of notification just few minutes after installing app on my phone or I don't disconnect the phone from computer.

For example - yesterday at 22:30 I set the alarm on 7:30 today and it didn't work, then (at 7:40) I connect the phone to computer, install the app again, set the alarm on 8 and it works, so I set another alarm on 21:30 and it didn't work again.

Any tips or something? I think I tried everything I know :/

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton notificationButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nofication_button);

    notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (curHr > 21)
            {
                // Since current hour is over 21, setting the date to the next day
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 12);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the NotificationReceiver class:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("Notification Text")
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```